# Llamar a una función Java desde C# en Unity

Tags: java, android, c#, unity

Necesito enviar datos desde c# a java y viceversa. Utilizo la función android java object. Ya se identificó que el momento donde se detiene es cuando se realiza la llamada a java con el `.Call()`.

Clase java

```
package cicese.mooding.brain.data.interaction;

public class Communication
{
  private int id;
  private String type;
  private String[] value;

  public Communication() {}

  public int GetID()
  {
    return id;
  }

  public void SetID(int value)
  {
    id = value;
  }

  public String GetType()
  {
    return type;
  }

  public void SetType(String value)
  {
    type = value;
  }

  public String[] GetValue()
  {
    return value;
  }

  public void SetValue(String[] value)
  {
    this.value = value;
  }

}
```

Codigo c# en unity (queremos llamar a la función `SetValue`)

```
public void Response()
{
  AndroidJavaObject manager = new AndroidJavaObject("cicese.mooding.brain.BrainManager");
  AndroidJavaObject response = new AndroidJavaObject("cicese.mooding.brain.data.interaction.Communication");
  string stringParameter = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name;

    object[] args = new object[] { stringParameter };
    response.Call("SetValue",args);

    args = new object[] { response };

   AndroidJavaObject data = manager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("receiveDataFromGUI", args);

   inter = Interaction.AndroidJavaToCSharp(data); 
}
```

Comment: manda algún error? Porque la clase que llamas BrainManager no la pusiste y así no hay mucha forma de ayudarte de momento